# How to refresh the page for all users?

Tags: php

I have a button in my admin panel area and blog page.
I want when I click on the button, the blog page will refresh to all the users.

It is possible?

Comment: what you mean by refresh to all users ?

Comment: not sure why you want to. But you can have every page poll the db via ajax and if it sees a flag refresh.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make on every webpage an AJAX call that triggers every one or two seconds. In the AJAX call you can check if you pressed the refresh button, this action you should save in a txt file or inside a database. When you pressed the refresh button you can do the page refresh with JavaScript.

Hope this is helpfull for you

Comment: To iterate on what J Quest said, it would just be easier to make a listener in Ajax to look for changes, if said changes are found or new updated item, then refresh that page with JS or update the view with the newer information. Depending on what JS frameworks you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods. First reload you data grid via Ajax to render page without page loading. 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Second is loading via JavaScript native function.
Force Reload
If you want to just stick with reloading the page as is, try onclick='window.location.reload(true);' instead of onclick='window.location.reload()'. The true parameter forces a get request to the server. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp